# Have I killed my avocado plant?

Tags: leaves, pruning, avocado

I have just planted my avocado seed in soil, and it had grown about 30 cm tall. I read online that you were supposed to cut it back when it was still around 20 cm so two weeks ago I did what everyone was saying. Now it’s been 2 weeks and no new leaves have grown out. I can see what look like tiny leaves around the stem but they have been there since day 1 and don’t seem to be growing (a couple have fallen off too). I don't think I have killed it since it's been two weeks and the stem is still green... My question is, has this happened to any of you? Do you think I killed it or there's something I can do, or do I just have to wait and pray?
Please help me :)

EDIT: You were right! My avocado after a month was able to push out new leaves from the side! Now it’s kind of funny because it has a cactus shape but it’s a great example of resilience. I will never cut it back again unless has grown a lot I promise!

Comment: Were any leaves left on the stem, or did you just hae stem left after the cut?

Comment: I tried to add a photo but the website won’t let me, now I just have the green stem that’s 30cm tall (hasn’t grown not even 1cm in 2 weeks) and 3/4 buds that aren’t growing leaves though.

Answer (score 1):

Avocados take a bit of time to adjust to changes; you have made two major changes (moving to soil in a pot and cutting back) and in moving there may have been some damage to the main tap root as well. All should still be good, it is quite normal for avocado to look as if it is doing nothing for a while, after which it makes surprising rapid growth. So just maintain it nicely moist, only water a little when very dry, keep it very well drained and give no fertilizer until it starts to grow again. Patience is the top requirement at this point.

Comment: Ok thank you so much you gave me hope! Yeah I reckon mine was not a smart move, I’ll definitely only prune it a little bit once it has grown leaves in the future!